# Manipulating default django stdout logs

Tags: django

Whenever I visit my django admin I see this in my logs

`[2018-08-13 15:41:55 +0800] [95] [DEBUG] GET /admin/login/
172.18.0.4 - - [13/Aug/2018:15:41:55 +0800] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 1859 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
[2018-08-13 15:41:55 +0800] [95] [DEBUG] Closing connection.`

I want to manipulate the line which displays `172.18.0.4 - - [13/Aug/2018:15:41:55 +0800] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.0" 200 1859 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6)`. How can I change the format of that part?

**UPDATE:**
I got it now, It was a gunicorn logs. I have to change the access_log configuration to solve my problem

Comment: This is handled by Django logging: you can change the format: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/

Comment: However it did not work

Answer (score 1):

You should check [Django docs | Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/#configuring-logging). There are specified some simple and few complex configurations of loging in django. This also answers your question about printing to stdout.

### EDIT:

Try adding for example to your base `settings.py` following lines and restart the server.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': 'LOG: {levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

You should see the difference in the console. Check **examples** in the link I've provided. This should definitely work.

Comment: Maybe you did not configure it properly. I'll edit my answer with more details. @DeanChristianArmada

Comment: I got it now, It was a gunicorn logs. I have to change the access_log configuration to solve my problem